# Maven launch configurations in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

while running maven from eclipse you have option to execute these launch configurations by default .. here is the image of that :

[image]

Now I can add my own launch configurations and execute them. Like this :

[image]

Now instead of running run configurations every time, is it possible that I put my own launch configuration called "Clean install skip tests with assembly" instead of default run configuration #1(Maven assembly:assembly) or can I add #10 configuration to be my created configuration. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now instead of running run configurations every time, is it possible that I put my own launch configuration called "Clean install skip tests with assembly" instead of default run configuration #1(Maven assembly:assembly) or can I add #10 configuration to be my created configuration.

I don't think so. But once you've run your **Maven Build** Run Configuration, it should be listed under the "**Run As...**" green arrow:

[alt text http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/8510/screenshotrun.png](http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/8510/screenshotrun.png)

And you can add it as favorite if you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you select `Run As > 2 Maven Build` (the one with the shortcut. It may not always be `2`) you can choose which run configuration to use from a simpler dialog - including your custom.

Comment: @Bozho true I can choose, but I don't want to run every time run as configuration than type in clean ... and then run , it would be easier if I could set my configuration to be with this other ones so I can do it with 2 clicks instead of 4 .. if that is possible that is ..

Answer (score 0):

For skipping tests dont add -D in the goals field. Use the "Skip Tests" checkbox that is below the Profiles input box adn it should work :)

Comment: @Bozho good point, it works either way but your way is simpler.. but that was not the question